# texture buffer object without shader

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

all tutorials online are written in opengl 3+ with intesive use of shader.

I was wondering, can I create a texture buffer object and show the texture without using shader? In very old opengl uber deprecate api calls you can write gltexcoord, I just tried this way only to see if my loader was OK, and it's alright.

Using TBO I'm encountering some problems..

Let's suppose I'm creating a quad, then after loading the image (named txtr), I will store coordinates in a vector

```
terrainTBO.push_back(1);
terrainTBO.push_back(1);

terrainTBO.push_back(0);
terrainTBO.push_back(1);

terrainTBO.push_back(1);
terrainTBO.push_back(0);

terrainTBO.push_back(0);
terrainTBO.push_back(0);
```

then, in initializing process of terrain I'm doing
(obviously I'm not writing here about vertices and indices)

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *texture_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vectorSizeOf(*texture_indices), &(*texture_indices)[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

In drawing part:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glhBindTexture(txtr);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vboId);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *tboId);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, *iboId);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (*indices).size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

The quad is created correctly, but no texture is shown into.. How can I achieve my texture? Is shader mandatory in these cases?

Comment: There's no way to "enable" the `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` texture target in the fixed-function (non-shader) pipeline, so that should rule out being able to use them without shaders. You might be able to do the same sort of thing with a 1D texture and a Pixel Buffer Object though, but that sounds like a heck of a lot more work than writing a simple shader.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will enable shaders so. @AndonM.Coleman If I can ask you one more thing, have I to create both vertex and fragment shader in the same loader or I can create first the vertex shader and then the fragment? It just my curiosity, not a matter of performance

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but I can tell you that OpenGL uses something called "shader programs." Think of these like a C++ program, each shader is like a ".cpp" (translation unit) file - you compile them and then link them together to create a finished program. The thing is, OpenGL's original design requires you to link a vertex shader and a fragment shader together into a single program. You can reuse vertex or fragment shaders in different linked programs, but every linked program needs to contain both.